Custom widget in the choice field Django
I'm passing a form to the template. I need from this template to then pass to another template the option that the user has selected. In this case, one of the payment options. I can do this with ChoiceField, select built-in widget=RadioSelect() and so on. But the ChoiceField should look like this:

When you select an option, it is highlighted with an orange box.
That is, I have no text at all, and I need to pass it to the handler in views.py.
I'm using Django 4.0. How do I do that?
class CheckoutForm(forms.Form):
    payment_method = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=CHOICES,
        widget=...
    )

<div class="checkout__payment-method checkout__payment-method--yookassa">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none"
         height="35" viewBox="0 0 266 64" width="145">
        <g fill="#0a2540">
            <path d="m136.578 19.3674h-8.748l-6.191 10.7836h-3.187l-.101-23.33758h-8.282v42.14848h8.282l.101-11.5682h3.167l8.22 11.5682h9.175l-10.717-15.3304z"></path>
            <path d="m199.259 33.2494c-1.683-1.0793-3.506-1.9254-5.42-2.5149l-1.827-.684-.494-.1839c-1.135-.4216-2.327-.8648-2.368-2.009-.01-.3397.066-.6765.222-.9791s.387-.561.672-.7511c.599-.4097 1.302-.6465 2.029-.6841 1.586-.1085 3.158.3561 4.425 1.3078l.224.1408 4.425-5.0498-.224-.181c-.551-.4868-1.149-.9181-1.786-1.2876-1.141-.6472-2.383-1.1027-3.674-1.348-1.86-.3922-3.783-.3922-5.643 0-1.798.2359-3.504.929-4.953 2.0119-.926.7182-1.7 1.6103-2.278 2.6252-.578 1.0148-.949 2.1327-1.091 3.2896-.254 2.0879.281 4.195 1.502 5.9149 1.622 1.7799 3.742 3.0406 6.089 3.6213l.366.1208.832.2816c3.004 1.006 3.857 1.4083 4.344 2.0119.226.3036.354.6686.365 1.0461 0 1.4285-1.766 2.0119-2.963 2.374-.838.1559-1.698.14-2.529-.0469s-1.615-.5406-2.302-1.0395c-1.113-.7375-2.065-1.6883-2.801-2.7964-.123.1268-.53.5299-1.062 1.0568-1.493 1.479-3.971 3.9336-3.911 3.9929l.142.2012c2.21 2.7429 5.307 4.647 8.768 5.3918.791.1516 1.592.2524 2.396.3018h.832c2.734.0568 5.413-.7694 7.632-2.3539 1.501-1.0522 2.652-2.5228 3.309-4.2249.399-1.1427.54-2.3582.414-3.5609-.126-1.2028-.517-2.3634-1.145-3.4001-.642-1.0339-1.5-1.919-2.517-2.5953z"></path>
            <path d="m220.614 30.7343c1.907.5896 3.724 1.4357 5.399 2.5148.999.6764 1.842 1.5539 2.476 2.5752.628 1.0368 1.019 2.1974 1.145 3.4001.126 1.2028-.015 2.4183-.414 3.561-.656 1.7021-1.808 3.1726-3.309 4.2249-2.219 1.5844-4.898 2.4106-7.632 2.3538h-.832c-.804-.0481-1.604-.1489-2.395-.3017-3.462-.7448-6.558-2.6489-8.769-5.3918l-.162-.2012c-.04-.0528 1.917-1.9991 3.397-3.4696.777-.7724 1.422-1.4139 1.576-1.5802.747 1.0993 1.697 2.0482 2.801 2.7965.691.4994 1.478.8533 2.312 1.0402.834.1868 1.698.2025 2.539.0462 1.198-.3621 2.943-.9456 2.943-2.374.011-.3778-.111-.7476-.345-1.0462-.487-.6035-1.339-1.0059-4.364-2.0118l-.832-.2817-.345-.1207c-2.348-.5807-4.468-1.8414-6.09-3.6213-1.231-1.715-1.767-3.8263-1.502-5.9149.149-1.1567.527-2.273 1.112-3.2846s1.366-1.8986 2.298-2.6101c1.452-1.0766 3.157-1.769 4.953-2.0119 1.867-.3927 3.796-.3927 5.663 0 1.285.246 2.52.7015 3.654 1.348.647.3644 1.252.796 1.807 1.2875l.203.1811-4.425 5.0498-.203-.1409c-1.269-.9483-2.84-1.4125-4.425-1.3077-.728.0376-1.431.2744-2.03.6841-.278.1977-.505.4572-.664.7576-.159.3005-.244.6335-.25.9726.061 1.1467 1.239 1.5893 2.396 2.0118l.466.1811z"></path>
            <path clip-rule="evenodd"
                  d="m163.777 19.3673v2.8971h-.365c-2.267-2.2497-5.338-3.5221-8.546-3.5409-1.966-.0385-3.919.3339-5.73 1.0931-1.812.7591-3.442 1.8879-4.784 3.3129-2.707 3.0045-4.159 6.9176-4.06 10.9445-.105 4.0944 1.344 8.0789 4.06 11.1658 1.31 1.4259 2.914 2.5556 4.704 3.3124s3.723 1.1229 5.668 1.0735c3.212-.0598 6.301-1.2346 8.728-3.3196h.325v2.5953h8.607v-29.5341zm.426 14.8676c.087 2.3801-.715 4.7081-2.253 6.5386-.737.8178-1.646 1.4652-2.663 1.8963s-2.117.6353-3.223.5984c-1.072.0179-2.135-.2044-3.109-.6503-.973-.4459-1.833-1.1039-2.514-1.9249-1.519-1.8684-2.298-4.2218-2.192-6.619-.069-2.3252.726-4.5945 2.233-6.3776.694-.8086 1.56-1.4552 2.535-1.8934.976-.4382 2.037-.6573 3.108-.6415 1.098-.0339 2.19.174 3.198.6089 1.007.4349 1.904 1.0858 2.627 1.9059 1.537 1.8385 2.339 4.1726 2.253 6.5586z"
                  fill-rule="evenodd"></path>
            <path clip-rule="evenodd"
                  d="m257.394 22.2646v-2.897h8.606v29.5341h-8.606v-2.5953h-.325c-2.428 2.085-5.517 3.2597-8.728 3.3195-1.946.0494-3.879-.3167-5.668-1.0734-1.79-.7568-3.395-1.8865-4.705-3.3124-2.716-3.0869-4.164-7.0714-4.059-11.1658-.099-4.0269 1.352-7.94 4.059-10.9446 1.348-1.4235 2.982-2.5511 4.796-3.31 1.815-.7589 3.77-1.1322 5.739-1.0959 3.201.024 6.263 1.296 8.525 3.5408zm-1.827 18.5092c1.546-1.8257 2.349-4.1571 2.253-6.5386.095-2.3875-.708-4.7249-2.253-6.5587-.723-.82-1.621-1.471-2.628-1.9058-1.007-.4349-2.1-.6429-3.198-.609-1.071-.0157-2.132.2033-3.107.6416-.976.4382-1.842 1.0848-2.536 1.8934-1.507 1.783-2.301 4.0524-2.232 6.3776-.107 2.3972.673 4.7506 2.192 6.619.681.821 1.54 1.4789 2.514 1.9248.973.4459 2.036.6682 3.108.6504 1.106.0369 2.206-.1674 3.223-.5985 1.018-.4311 1.927-1.0784 2.664-1.8962z"
                  fill-rule="evenodd"></path>
        </g>
        <path clip-rule="evenodd"
              d="m26.4424 31.7092c.0477-17.4683 14.4906-31.7092 32.6397-31.7092 17.9726 0 32.8465 14.288 32.6399 31.7959 0 17.5079-14.6673 31.7959-32.6399 31.7959-17.9431 0-32.5917-14.0406-32.6397-31.7088v23.6592h-11.5685l-14.8739-46.2852h26.4424zm20.4514.0867c0 6.4397 5.5777 11.8732 12.1883 11.8732 6.8172 0 12.1884-5.4335 12.1884-11.8732s-5.5777-11.8731-12.1884-11.8731c-6.6106 0-12.1883 5.4334-12.1883 11.8731z"
              fill="#0070f0" fill-rule="evenodd"></path>
    </svg>
</div>
<div class="checkout__payment-method checkout__payment-method--freekassa">
    <svg width="110" height="35" viewBox="0 0 110 35"
         fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M10.6948 5.12001H3.67984V9.95001H9.42984V11.56H3.67984V18H1.83984V3.51001H10.6948V5.12001ZM21.3898 18L17.9398 12.02H15.1798V18H13.3398V3.51001H18.7448C19.9408 3.51001 20.9678 3.93201 21.8268 4.77501C22.6858 5.61801 23.1148 6.61501 23.1148 7.76501C23.1148 8.39401 22.9998 8.96901 22.7698 9.49001C22.5548 9.99601 22.2948 10.395 21.9878 10.686C21.6954 10.9513 21.3798 11.1899 21.0448 11.399C20.7378 11.599 20.4698 11.729 20.2398 11.79L19.9178 11.905L23.4598 18H21.3898ZM15.1798 5.12001V10.41H18.7448C19.4348 10.41 20.0248 10.157 20.5158 9.65101C20.7621 9.40341 20.9562 9.1089 21.0865 8.78495C21.2169 8.46099 21.2809 8.11416 21.2748 7.76501C21.2748 7.02901 21.0218 6.40801 20.5158 5.90201C20.0258 5.38101 19.4348 5.12001 18.7448 5.12001H15.1798ZM27.9378 16.39H35.5278V18H26.0978V3.51001H35.2978V5.12001H27.9378V9.72001H34.7228V11.33H27.9378V16.39ZM40.3578 16.39H47.9478V18H38.5178V3.51001H47.7178V5.12001H40.3578V9.72001H47.1438V11.33H40.3588L40.3578 16.39Z"
              fill="#FA5745"></path>
        <path d="M52.7795 3.51002V18H50.9395V3.51002H52.7795ZM58.8745 18L52.7795 10.64L58.4145 3.51002H60.5995L54.8495 10.64L61.0595 18H58.8745ZM71.6315 18L70.2515 14.435H64.2715L62.8915 18H60.9355L66.4555 3.51002H68.0655L73.5865 18H71.6315ZM67.2615 6.50002L64.8465 12.825H69.6765L67.2595 6.50002H67.2615ZM74.6165 7.30502C74.6165 6.29302 75.0685 5.38802 75.9735 4.59102C76.8785 3.79402 77.9975 3.39502 79.3315 3.39502C80.5885 3.39502 81.6465 3.82502 82.5055 4.68302C83.3795 5.52602 83.8165 6.55302 83.8165 7.76502H81.9765C81.9765 6.96802 81.7235 6.30802 81.2175 5.78702C80.7115 5.26602 80.0825 5.00502 79.3315 5.00502C78.5035 5.00502 77.8135 5.24302 77.2615 5.71802C76.7245 6.17802 76.4565 6.70702 76.4565 7.30502C76.4565 7.94902 76.7165 8.47002 77.2385 8.86902C77.7755 9.26802 78.4185 9.58202 79.1705 9.81202C79.9215 10.027 80.6735 10.272 81.4245 10.548C82.1915 10.824 82.8345 11.268 83.3565 11.882C83.8935 12.48 84.1615 13.254 84.1615 14.205C84.1615 15.278 83.7165 16.198 82.8275 16.965C81.9375 17.732 80.7725 18.115 79.3315 18.115C77.8595 18.115 76.6865 17.709 75.8125 16.896C74.9385 16.083 74.5015 15.033 74.5015 13.745H76.3415C76.3415 14.619 76.5945 15.301 77.1005 15.792C77.6215 16.267 78.3655 16.505 79.3315 16.505C80.2665 16.505 80.9955 16.29 81.5165 15.861C82.0535 15.416 82.3215 14.864 82.3215 14.205C82.3215 13.561 82.0535 13.04 81.5165 12.641C80.9955 12.242 80.3585 11.936 79.6075 11.721C78.8565 11.491 78.0975 11.238 77.3305 10.962C76.5878 10.6919 75.9239 10.2413 75.3985 9.65102C74.8775 9.03802 74.6165 8.25602 74.6165 7.30502ZM86.0045 7.30502C86.0045 6.29302 86.4565 5.38802 87.3615 4.59102C88.2655 3.79402 89.3855 3.39502 90.7195 3.39502C91.9765 3.39502 93.0345 3.82502 93.8935 4.68302C94.7675 5.52602 95.2035 6.55302 95.2035 7.76502H93.3635C93.3635 6.96802 93.1115 6.30802 92.6055 5.78702C92.0995 5.26602 91.4705 5.00502 90.7195 5.00502C89.8915 5.00502 89.2015 5.24302 88.6495 5.71802C88.1125 6.17802 87.8445 6.70702 87.8445 7.30502C87.8445 7.94902 88.1045 8.47002 88.6265 8.86902C89.1625 9.26802 89.8065 9.58202 90.5585 9.81202C91.3095 10.027 92.0605 10.272 92.8125 10.548C93.5785 10.824 94.2225 11.268 94.7445 11.882C95.2805 12.48 95.5495 13.254 95.5495 14.205C95.5495 15.278 95.1045 16.198 94.2155 16.965C93.3255 17.732 92.1605 18.115 90.7195 18.115C89.2475 18.115 88.0745 17.709 87.1995 16.896C86.3265 16.083 85.8895 15.033 85.8895 13.745H87.7295C87.7295 14.619 87.9825 15.301 88.4885 15.792C89.0095 16.267 89.7535 16.505 90.7185 16.505C91.6545 16.505 92.3825 16.29 92.9045 15.861C93.4405 15.416 93.7095 14.864 93.7095 14.205C93.7095 13.561 93.4405 13.04 92.9045 12.641C92.3825 12.242 91.7465 11.936 90.9945 11.721C90.2445 11.491 89.4845 11.238 88.7185 10.962C87.9758 10.6919 87.3119 10.2413 86.7865 9.65102C86.2645 9.03802 86.0045 8.25602 86.0045 7.30502ZM107.051 18L105.671 14.435H99.6915L98.3115 18H96.3565L101.876 3.51002H103.486L109.006 18H107.051ZM102.681 6.50002L100.266 12.825H105.096L102.681 6.50002Z"
              fill="white"></path>
        <path d="M2.39416 25.24C2.01116 25.66 1.82016 26.197 1.82016 26.85C1.82016 27.503 2.01116 28.04 2.39416 28.46C2.77716 28.88 3.23916 29.09 3.78016 29.09C4.32116 29.09 4.78316 28.88 5.16616 28.46C5.54916 28.04 5.74016 27.503 5.74016 26.85C5.74016 26.197 5.54916 25.66 5.16616 25.24C4.78316 24.82 4.32116 24.61 3.78016 24.61C3.23916 24.61 2.77716 24.82 2.39416 25.24ZM1.68016 23.7L1.96016 24.4C2.00716 24.344 2.07716 24.274 2.17016 24.19C2.26316 24.106 2.47316 23.994 2.80016 23.854C3.12716 23.704 3.47716 23.63 3.85016 23.63C4.67116 23.63 5.36716 23.933 5.93616 24.54C6.50616 25.147 6.79016 25.917 6.79016 26.85C6.79016 27.783 6.50516 28.553 5.93616 29.16C5.36616 29.767 4.67116 30.07 3.85016 30.07C3.47716 30.07 3.13116 30 2.81416 29.86C2.50616 29.72 2.28716 29.58 2.15616 29.44L1.96016 29.23V32.24H0.910156V23.7H1.68016ZM10.5632 23.63C11.2542 23.63 11.8232 23.84 12.2712 24.26C12.7192 24.68 12.9432 25.193 12.9432 25.8V30H12.1732L11.8932 29.3C11.828 29.3747 11.7579 29.4449 11.6832 29.51C11.5902 29.594 11.3802 29.71 11.0532 29.86C10.7272 30 10.3772 30.07 10.0032 30.07C9.38716 30.07 8.88316 29.888 8.49116 29.524C8.30235 29.3554 8.1521 29.148 8.05063 28.9161C7.94917 28.6842 7.89887 28.4331 7.90316 28.18C7.90316 27.527 8.19716 27.027 8.78516 26.682C9.37316 26.327 10.4092 26.15 11.8932 26.15V25.8C11.8932 25.483 11.7632 25.207 11.5012 24.974C11.3768 24.8541 11.2299 24.7601 11.0688 24.6976C10.9077 24.6351 10.7358 24.6053 10.5632 24.61C9.87316 24.61 9.45316 24.913 9.30316 25.52H8.18316C8.25816 24.97 8.50516 24.517 8.92516 24.162C9.34516 23.807 9.89116 23.63 10.5632 23.63ZM10.0032 29.09C10.5352 29.09 10.9832 28.94 11.3472 28.642C11.7112 28.334 11.8932 27.993 11.8932 27.62V27.13C10.7172 27.13 9.93316 27.219 9.54116 27.396C9.14916 27.573 8.95316 27.858 8.95316 28.25C8.95316 28.474 9.05116 28.67 9.24716 28.838C9.44316 29.006 9.69516 29.09 10.0032 29.09ZM16.3712 29.86L13.9212 23.7H15.0412L16.9312 28.53L18.8212 23.7H19.9412L17.2112 30.56C16.9592 31.195 16.6932 31.643 16.4132 31.904C16.1432 32.174 15.8022 32.31 15.3912 32.31L14.9712 32.24V31.4C15.2702 31.4 15.4992 31.335 15.6572 31.204C15.8252 31.074 15.9702 30.859 16.0912 30.56L16.3712 29.86ZM27.2242 23.63C27.8032 23.63 28.2972 23.868 28.7082 24.344C29.1182 24.82 29.3242 25.445 29.3242 26.22V30H28.2742V26.22C28.2742 25.716 28.1532 25.324 27.9102 25.044C27.8055 24.9063 27.6698 24.7953 27.5141 24.7199C27.3584 24.6444 27.1871 24.6068 27.0142 24.61C26.6502 24.61 26.3372 24.76 26.0762 25.058C25.8152 25.357 25.6842 25.744 25.6842 26.22V30H24.6342V26.22C24.6342 25.716 24.5132 25.324 24.2702 25.044C24.1655 24.9063 24.0297 24.7953 23.8741 24.7199C23.7184 24.6444 23.5471 24.6068 23.3742 24.61C23.0192 24.61 22.7072 24.764 22.4362 25.072C22.1752 25.38 22.0442 25.762 22.0442 26.22V30H20.9942V23.7H21.7642L22.0442 24.4C22.0605 24.3706 22.0793 24.3425 22.1002 24.316C22.1282 24.279 22.1892 24.218 22.2822 24.134C22.3741 24.0417 22.4777 23.9617 22.5902 23.896C22.7022 23.831 22.8472 23.77 23.0242 23.714C23.2012 23.658 23.3882 23.63 23.5842 23.63C23.9572 23.63 24.2892 23.723 24.5782 23.91C24.8682 24.097 25.0682 24.283 25.1802 24.47L25.3342 24.75C25.3532 24.722 25.3762 24.685 25.4042 24.638C25.4322 24.582 25.5022 24.488 25.6142 24.358C25.7262 24.228 25.8472 24.115 25.9782 24.022C26.1414 23.9076 26.3207 23.8179 26.5102 23.756C26.7342 23.672 26.9722 23.63 27.2242 23.63ZM35.0602 28.32H36.1802C35.9472 28.824 35.6102 29.244 35.1722 29.58C34.7342 29.907 34.2062 30.07 33.5902 30.07C32.7692 30.07 32.0732 29.767 31.5042 29.16C30.9342 28.553 30.6502 27.783 30.6502 26.85C30.6502 25.926 30.9302 25.16 31.4902 24.554C32.0602 23.938 32.7362 23.63 33.5202 23.63C34.3042 23.63 34.9672 23.924 35.5082 24.512C36.0492 25.1 36.3202 25.856 36.3202 26.78L36.2502 27.34H31.7702C31.8082 27.797 32.0082 28.203 32.3722 28.558C32.7362 28.913 33.1422 29.09 33.5902 29.09C34.1872 29.09 34.6772 28.833 35.0602 28.32ZM33.5202 24.61C33.1002 24.61 32.7172 24.783 32.3722 25.128C32.0362 25.473 31.8352 25.908 31.7702 26.43H35.2002C35.1352 25.88 34.9432 25.44 34.6262 25.114C34.3182 24.778 33.9502 24.61 33.5202 24.61ZM40.5852 23.63C41.2662 23.63 41.8452 23.887 42.3212 24.4C42.7972 24.913 43.0352 25.567 43.0352 26.36V30H41.9852V26.36C41.9852 25.847 41.8352 25.427 41.5372 25.1C41.4016 24.944 41.2337 24.8193 41.0451 24.7347C40.8566 24.6501 40.6518 24.6076 40.4452 24.61C39.9502 24.61 39.5442 24.773 39.2272 25.1C38.9192 25.417 38.7652 25.837 38.7652 26.36V30H37.7152V23.7H38.4852L38.7652 24.4C38.8112 24.344 38.8812 24.274 38.9752 24.19C39.0682 24.106 39.2692 23.994 39.5772 23.854C39.8942 23.704 40.2302 23.63 40.5852 23.63ZM45.4132 22.93V22.02H46.3232V23.7H47.7232V24.68H46.3232V27.97C46.3232 28.315 46.4162 28.59 46.6032 28.796C46.7992 28.992 47.0562 29.09 47.3732 29.09L47.7232 29.02V29.93C47.5832 30.023 47.3732 30.07 47.0932 30.07C46.5892 30.07 46.1602 29.874 45.8052 29.482C45.4502 29.09 45.2732 28.586 45.2732 27.97V24.68H44.1532V23.7H44.6432C45.1562 23.7 45.4132 23.443 45.4132 22.93ZM56.4052 28.18C56.4052 28.721 56.2052 29.174 55.8032 29.538C55.4112 29.893 54.8892 30.07 54.2352 30.07C53.5542 30.07 53.0082 29.888 52.5972 29.524C52.1872 29.16 51.9632 28.689 51.9252 28.11H52.9752C53.0132 28.4 53.1392 28.637 53.3532 28.824C53.5682 29.001 53.8622 29.09 54.2352 29.09C54.5712 29.09 54.8422 29.001 55.0472 28.824C55.1437 28.7468 55.2215 28.6488 55.2748 28.5372C55.3281 28.4257 55.3556 28.3036 55.3552 28.18C55.3586 28.0625 55.329 27.9463 55.2695 27.8448C55.2101 27.7433 55.1234 27.6606 55.0192 27.606C54.7952 27.466 54.5192 27.363 54.1932 27.298C53.8762 27.223 53.5532 27.139 53.2272 27.046C52.9048 26.9554 52.617 26.7701 52.4012 26.514C52.1772 26.244 52.0652 25.889 52.0652 25.45C52.0652 24.946 52.2612 24.517 52.6532 24.162C53.0452 23.807 53.5492 23.63 54.1652 23.63C54.8192 23.63 55.3322 23.803 55.7052 24.148C56.0882 24.493 56.2982 24.951 56.3352 25.52H55.2852C55.2112 24.913 54.8372 24.61 54.1652 24.61C53.8672 24.61 53.6152 24.694 53.4092 24.862C53.2132 25.03 53.1152 25.226 53.1152 25.45C53.1152 25.702 53.2272 25.898 53.4512 26.038C53.6752 26.168 53.9462 26.271 54.2632 26.346C54.5902 26.411 54.9172 26.491 55.2432 26.584C55.5702 26.677 55.8452 26.859 56.0692 27.13C56.2932 27.391 56.4052 27.741 56.4052 28.18ZM59.4792 29.86L57.0292 23.7H58.1492L60.0392 28.53L61.9292 23.7H63.0492L60.3192 30.56C60.0672 31.195 59.8012 31.643 59.5212 31.904C59.2502 32.174 58.9092 32.31 58.4992 32.31L58.0792 32.24V31.4C58.3772 31.4 58.6062 31.335 58.7652 31.204C58.9332 31.074 59.0772 30.859 59.1992 30.56L59.4792 29.86ZM68.2312 28.18C68.2312 28.721 68.0312 29.174 67.6292 29.538C67.2372 29.893 66.7151 30.07 66.0611 30.07C65.3811 30.07 64.8342 29.888 64.4232 29.524C64.0132 29.16 63.7892 28.689 63.7512 28.11H64.8012C64.832 28.3873 64.9672 28.6426 65.1792 28.824C65.3941 29.001 65.6891 29.09 66.0611 29.09C66.3971 29.09 66.6682 29.001 66.8732 28.824C66.9696 28.7467 67.0474 28.6487 67.1007 28.5372C67.154 28.4257 67.1815 28.3036 67.1812 28.18C67.1846 28.0625 67.155 27.9463 67.0955 27.8448C67.0361 27.7433 66.9494 27.6606 66.8452 27.606C66.6212 27.466 66.3462 27.363 66.0191 27.298C65.7021 27.223 65.3802 27.139 65.0532 27.046C64.7307 26.9555 64.443 26.7701 64.2272 26.514C64.0032 26.244 63.8912 25.889 63.8912 25.45C63.8912 24.946 64.0872 24.517 64.4792 24.162C64.8712 23.807 65.3752 23.63 65.9911 23.63C66.6451 23.63 67.1581 23.803 67.5312 24.148C67.9142 24.493 68.1242 24.951 68.1612 25.52H67.1112C67.0372 24.913 66.6631 24.61 65.9911 24.61C65.6932 24.61 65.4412 24.694 65.2352 24.862C65.0392 25.03 64.9412 25.226 64.9412 25.45C64.9412 25.702 65.0532 25.898 65.2772 26.038C65.5012 26.168 65.7721 26.271 66.0891 26.346C66.4162 26.411 66.7432 26.491 67.0692 26.584C67.3962 26.677 67.6712 26.859 67.8951 27.13C68.1191 27.391 68.2312 27.741 68.2312 28.18ZM70.2551 22.93V22.02H71.1652V23.7H72.5652V24.68H71.1652V27.97C71.1652 28.315 71.2582 28.59 71.4452 28.796C71.6412 28.992 71.8981 29.09 72.2151 29.09L72.5652 29.02V29.93C72.4252 30.023 72.2151 30.07 71.9352 30.07C71.4312 30.07 71.0012 29.874 70.6472 29.482C70.2922 29.09 70.1152 28.586 70.1152 27.97V24.68H68.9952V23.7H69.4852C69.9982 23.7 70.2551 23.443 70.2551 22.93ZM77.9632 28.32H79.0832C78.8559 28.8165 78.5097 29.2493 78.0751 29.58C77.6351 29.907 77.1091 30.07 76.4931 30.07C75.6712 30.07 74.9762 29.767 74.4062 29.16C73.8372 28.553 73.5522 27.783 73.5522 26.85C73.5522 25.926 73.8322 25.16 74.3922 24.554C74.9622 23.938 75.6382 23.63 76.4221 23.63C77.2072 23.63 77.8692 23.924 78.4112 24.512C78.9512 25.1 79.2222 25.856 79.2222 26.78L79.1522 27.34H74.6721C74.7102 27.797 74.9112 28.203 75.2752 28.558C75.6382 28.913 76.0452 29.09 76.4931 29.09C77.0901 29.09 77.5801 28.833 77.9632 28.32ZM76.4231 24.61C76.0032 24.61 75.6202 24.783 75.2752 25.128C74.9382 25.473 74.7382 25.908 74.6721 26.43H78.1021C78.0371 25.88 77.8462 25.44 77.5282 25.114C77.2202 24.778 76.8531 24.61 76.4231 24.61ZM86.8472 23.63C87.4262 23.63 87.9202 23.868 88.3312 24.344C88.7412 24.82 88.9472 25.445 88.9472 26.22V30H87.8972V26.22C87.8972 25.716 87.7761 25.324 87.5331 25.044C87.4284 24.9063 87.2927 24.7953 87.1371 24.7199C86.9814 24.6444 86.8101 24.6068 86.6372 24.61C86.2732 24.61 85.9602 24.76 85.6992 25.058C85.4381 25.357 85.3072 25.744 85.3072 26.22V30H84.2572V26.22C84.2572 25.716 84.1361 25.324 83.8932 25.044C83.7884 24.9063 83.6527 24.7953 83.4971 24.7199C83.3414 24.6444 83.1701 24.6068 82.9972 24.61C82.6422 24.61 82.3302 24.764 82.0592 25.072C81.7981 25.38 81.6672 25.762 81.6672 26.22V30H80.6171V23.7H81.3872L81.6672 24.4C81.6836 24.3706 81.7023 24.3425 81.7232 24.316C81.7512 24.279 81.8121 24.218 81.9052 24.134C81.9982 24.041 82.1012 23.961 82.2132 23.896C82.3251 23.831 82.4702 23.77 82.6472 23.714C82.8242 23.658 83.0112 23.63 83.2072 23.63C83.5802 23.63 83.9121 23.723 84.2011 23.91C84.4911 24.097 84.6912 24.283 84.8032 24.47L84.9572 24.75C84.9762 24.722 84.9992 24.685 85.0272 24.638C85.0552 24.582 85.1252 24.488 85.2372 24.358C85.3492 24.228 85.4702 24.115 85.6012 24.022C85.7644 23.9076 85.9437 23.8179 86.1332 23.756C86.3572 23.672 86.5952 23.63 86.8472 23.63Z"
              fill="#888888"></path>
    </svg>
</div>

.checkout__payment-methods {
    display: flex;
    gap: 20px;
    height: 80px;
    margin-top: 25px;
}

.checkout__payment-method {
    border-radius: var(--border-radius-primary);
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    transition: filter .2s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.checkout__payment-method:hover {
    filter: brightness(80%);
}

.checkout__payment-method--yookassa {
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.checkout__payment-method--freekassa {
    background-color: #333342;
}

I tried using mark_safe to insert the code into the second CHOICES element, and then in the template using a loop to output the payment_method, but it didn't work as I expected
